# I'm trying to use a button trigger to move multiple gameobjects to and from their original transform positions to a single point

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, animation

I'm making an inventory system and want to use a button to move all items from under the button to a grid (which is their original transform coordinates). want to reference the coordinate to the original game object through their index, but it does not move at all. I'm not sure if the lists I have set up have nothing indexed, or the translation isn't working. what can I correct here to make this work?

```cs
public class BaseInventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> myObjects;
    public Vector3 rootV3;
    public float delayBetweenObjects = .1f;
    public float animationDuration = .1f;
    public List<Vector3> baseV3 = new List<Vector3>();
    public Vector3 endV3;
     
    void SavePositions()
    {
        foreach(GameObject g in myObjects)
        {
            baseV3.Add(g.transform.position);
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        Hide();
    }

    private void Hide()
    {
        foreach (GameObject g in myObjects)
        {
            g.SetActive(false);            
        }
    }

    public void ShowItems()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Show());
    }

    IEnumerator Show()
    {
        foreach (GameObject g in myObjects)
        {
            int i = myObjects.IndexOf(g);
            endV3 = baseV3[i];
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delayBetweenObjects);
            g.SetActive(true);
            g.transform.DOMove(endV3, animationDuration).From();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you take out the animation stuff? What do you mean when you say you "don't seem to be getting it right?" Does it move at all? Go to the wrong place? Have you verified your code is getting called?

Comment: hello @Chuck , the console returns the following when i click the button, and the script seems to run:
`ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

Comment: When do you `SavePositions()`? Try adding a call before `StartCoroutine()` in `ShowItems()`. I think the issue is that you're assuming a 1:1 relationship between `myObjects` and `baseV3`, but it looks like `myObjects` is assigned in Editor and `baseV3` is assigned in `SavePositions()`.